# facebook like problem Open popup frame facebook login

Tags: javascript

Hey guys as you know there facebook like box button

this code...

```
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.mercedes.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=300&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=verdana&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

[image]

but When I joined and clicked the like button  from iphone or iPad, Because of I m not online facebook opening login box...But different page I want to open login box on the same page and popup frame.... I hope you understand me..

I mean Look at the picture.. When clicked the like.. I want to black border page open popup frame..( login box ) not different page on the same page

Answer (score 0):

With the iFrame version of the like button you are limited to what they provide. There is no way to make the information open up within the current iframe because the code behind it is on Facebook.com

If you need more control over it, look into the Facebook JavaScript SDK:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/